# Sending a base64 data image via form POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, base64

I have two images in the form of (somewhat):

```
<img src="data: base64, OIJQWEFOIJQWEFOIJQWEF..." />
<img src="data: base64, OIJQWEFOIJQWEFOIJQWEF..." />
```

I have no choice in the matter, these images are always going to be set as base64 data.

If I were to POST these using some client side magic, how can I convert the strings to actual images?

```
public ActionResult Combine(string imageA, string imageB)
{
    // imageA and imageB would be the strings.
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) method.
This method:

> Converts the specified string, which encodes binary data as base-64
>   digits, to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer array.

Then you can use `WebImage` class from `System.Web.Helpers.dll` assembly to convert byte array to actual image and perform some manipulations on it.